# Let the focus S of parabola divide one of its focal chord in the ratio 2:1. If the tangent at Q cuts directrix at R such that RQ=6...

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Let the focus S of parabola divide one of its focal chord in the ratio 2:1. If the tangent at Q cuts directrix at R such that RQ=6, find distance of focus from tangent at P.

Let P and Q be $(at^2,2at)$ and $(\frac{a}{t^2}, \frac{-2a}{t})$ respectively, for parabola $y^2=4ax$

So $$0= 2(-\frac{2a}{t})+2at$$
$$\implies t^2=2$$

Now tangent at Q is

$$\frac{y}{\sqrt 2} =x+\frac a2$$

So point R is $(-a, -\frac{a}{\sqrt 2})$

Then $$QR^2 = 36$$
$$\implies a=\frac{12}{\sqrt {11}}$$

So now, tangent at P is $$\sqrt 2y=x+2a$$ whose distance from $(a,0)$ is
$$d=\left | \frac{a+2a}{\sqrt 3}\right|$$
$$d=\sqrt 3 a$$
$$d=\frac{\sqrt 3 \times 12}{\sqrt {11}}$$

But given answer is 4

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you finding length $PS$ or distance from $S$ to tangent at $P$ as they are two different things? Your question reads opposite of your working. For the first, the answer is $4\sqrt3$ and for the second it is indeed $4$.

Comment: @MathLover please check the edit. I corrected my sentence. The question is asking for distance between the line and the focus.

Comment: $4\sqrt 3$ is answer for what?

Comment: For given data I'm also getting $PS=4\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake lies in taking incorrect sign of $t$ for point $Q$. It lies on opposite side of $P$. So for $Q$, parameter is $-1/t=-1/\sqrt{2}$ but in the tangent equation at $Q$ you took $1/t=1/\sqrt{2}$ which gave wrong coordinates for $R$.

Since $(x,y)=(at^2,2at)$, $t$ has same sign as $y$. So the entire upper branch of a parabola has $t$ positive and entire lower branch has $t$ negative - something to keep in mind.

Comment: How? I kept $t>0$ in all cases, and added a minus sign for Q, making $y$ negative

Comment: @Aditya Equation for tangent at Q is $yt_Q = x+at_Q^2$ ie, $-y/t_P=x+a/t_P^2$ which is $-y/\sqrt{2}=x+a/2$.

Comment: Indeed. I mean to say, one branch has all $t$ of same sign, other branch has opposite sign. Since PQ is a focal chord, P,Q lie on different branches. Their signs of parameter $t$ must be opposite.

Comment: That's not the question. That's OP's solution part. They correctly took opposite signs in beginning but made mistake of taking same sign in writing equation for tangent at Q. We're assuming parabola is $y^2=4ax$.

Comment: oh ok sorry, that's the part I got confused with. I thought that was part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

As you rightly obtained, $t^2 = 2 \implies t = \pm \sqrt2$

If we take $t = \sqrt2$ and rewrite,

$P(2a, 2a \sqrt2), Q(\frac{a}{2}, - a \sqrt2)$

Slope of tangent at point $Q = \frac{2a}{y} = - \sqrt2$

So equation of tangent line $y + a \sqrt2 = -\sqrt2(x-\frac{a}{2})$

or $y = - \sqrt2 x - \frac{a}{\sqrt2} $

Point $R$ where the line intersects the directrix, $R(-a, \frac{a}{\sqrt2})$.

So $QR^2 = \frac{9a^2}{4} + \frac{9a^2}{2} = 36 \implies a = \frac{4}{\sqrt3}$.

Now slope of tangent line at $P = \frac{2a}{y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

So equation of tangent line at $P$, $y - 2a\sqrt2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(x - 2a)$

or $y = \frac{x}{\sqrt2} + \sqrt2 a$

Its distance from focus $(a,0)$ is

$d = \frac{3a/ \sqrt2}{\sqrt{3/2}} = a \sqrt3 = 4$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use coordinates for this problem. [Line $PR$ is the tangent at $P$ and triangle $PQR$ is right-angled at $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3839766/255730). Distance $FH$ is thus parallel to $QR$. By similar triangles:
$$
FH:QR=FP:QP=2:3,
\quad\text{hence:}\quad
FH={2\over3}QR=4.
$$