# Prove that two tangents to a parabola are perpendicular if their point of intersection lies on the directrix

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line, geometric-construction

$G_1$ is the axisymmetric image of  focus $F$ with respect to one tangent, and $G_2$ with respect to the other one. Let these tangents intersect at point $B$ on the directrix of the given parabola.

Because $\angle D_2BG_2=\angle GBG_1$ and $\angle D_2BF = \angle D_2BG_2$ , it follows that $\angle GBG_1= \angle D_2BF$. Since $\angle BG_1G=\angle BFD_2=90°$, and $|BF|=|BG_1|$ , $\triangle FD_2B$ is congruent to $\triangle G_1GB$, which implies that $|D_2B|=|BG|$ and
$\angle FD_2B=\angle G_1GB$. So now we know that the midpoint of $D_2G$ is $B$ and $\triangle D_2GD_1$ is isosceles which means that line $D_1B$ is a perpendicular bisector of $D_2G$.

[image]

Is this proof okay and are there any more elegant proofs?

Comment: 'The orthoptic curve of a parabola is its directrix" ; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoptic_(geometry))

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3839766/255730

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Will do. Thank you for sharing!!